# position logo and menu items on WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I am using the Astra theme on WordPress and Elementor as a page builder. My workflow was good Until suddenly ran I into a problem When I tried to search the options for positioning the menu items and the logo at both ends of the screen but I didn't find that option and I also tried to manipulate the HTML and played around the margins and padding but nothing happens. And please don't think this question might be on the internet I am searching for the answer for two days.
So please can anyone tell me how can I make the logo and the menu items at both ends of the screen rather than in the middle.
Here is the current image
[image: Here you can see the logo and the menu items at the center of the screen (Sorry I can show the logo because the website is under development)]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question more suited for [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try playing with the margin of logo as well as the menu items. or Just align the menu items on left and the logo on right. Either way you can still try checking out websites like w3schools.com that will guide you with you problem.

Comment: Please could you tell me a brief way to do this